# Multiple solutions of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**When $h>0$  is sufficent small**, we know that  the following ODE has unique solution
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=F(x,t)\\
x(0)=\xi~~~~~~~
$$
where $x(t)\in C^1[-h,h]$, $F(x,t)$ is  Lipschitz. It is proved by contracting mapping principle.  $h>0$  is sufficent small  makes
$$
T:x\rightarrow \xi + \int_0^tF(x(\tau),\tau)d\tau
$$
is contracting map. Therefore, it have unique fixed point.

So, I want to know, whether the $h>0$  is sufficent small  is the key point. If without conditions on $h>0$, whether there is any IVP with the above form has multiple solutions ?

Comment: The solution is only guaranteed to exist (and be continuously differentiable) on an interval around $t=0$. For example, the I.V.P. $x' = x^2$, $x(0) = 1$ has solution $x(t) = (1-t)^{-1}$, which can't be extended past the vertical asymptote at $x=1$. Hence, you only get solution on $[-h, h]$ for $h<1$.

Comment: There are examples where the Lipschitz condition is relaxed and you lose uniqueness of solutions. Consider the I.V.P. $x' = 3x^{2/3}$, $x(0)=0$. For any $a \geq 0$, the function $x_a(t)$ is a solution, where $x_a(t) = 0$ for $t \leq a$ and $x_a(t) = t^3$ for $t \geq a$.

Comment: @SammyBlack  Thanks, but I want to know the influence  of $h$  for multiple solutions.  So, I want to know whether there is any example which has multiple solutions  with the above form (I.V.P).